# Ошибка на строке 0

Tags: python, telegram-bot

пишу тг-бота на питоне, столкнулся с проблемой.

код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['calculator']) # line 122 
def calculator_task(message): # 123
    calc = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пример. \n ' # 124
                                  'Операторы: \n' # 125 
                                  '/ - разделить .\n' # 126 
                                  '* - умножить. \n' # 127
                                  '-/+ - отнять/прибавить соответсвенно. \n' # 128
                                  'x**y - степень. \n' # 129
                                  'sqrt(n) - корень квадратный. \n' # 130
                                  'pi - число Пи. \n' # 131
                                  'e - число e. \n') # 132
bot.register_next_step_handler(calc, mathf) # 133

def mathf(message): # 135
    ready_task = eval(calc) # 136
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{ready_task}') # 137
```

текст ошибки:

```
  File "C:/Users/КАЭС/Desktop/Python-files/python projects/telebot/multitoolbot/multitoolbot.py", line 137, in mathf
ready_task = eval(calc)
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

и еще, скорее всего я налажал с функцией

Comment: уберите кириллицу с имени пользователя и что вы пытаетесь сделать в 136й стоке?

Comment: @5c0rp, без этого никак?

Comment: Что по вашему возвращает bot.send_mesage? И что вы ожидали, запихивая результат этого вызова в eval?

Comment: @Xander сообщение пользователя - '10 + 10', или типа того. далее пример обрабатывается методом eval(), и результат отправляется пользователю

Comment: Вы в курсе, что bot.send_message ОТПРАВЛЯЕТ сообщение, а не принимает его от пользователя?

Comment: @Xander я не до конца понял, как пользоваться bot.register_next_step_handler(), поэтому скорее всего так и написал.